# Git resolve conflicts for all files on a path

Tags: git, conflict

Can someone help me on what is the right command that I can use for resolve conflicts for all files under a specific path with --ours strategy? 
I've tried so far:

`git checkout --ours public/
git checkout --ours public/*`

And all variants...

Comment: Before posting as an aswer, i'll post it as a comment, but try : git checkout --ours -- public/*

Comment: yeah I've tried that one too many times, with no luck